# Haskell array from list of strings

Tags: arrays, sorting, haskell

So I have a list of strings and the task is to count how many times each string can be met in that list. 
I used maps:

```
freqMap =  M.fromListWith (+) [(c, 1) | c <- subs]
```

and just sorting:

```
frequency list = map (\l -> (length l, head l)) $ group (sort list)
```

but it's all too slow for my task - the original list is very large.
I've heard, that using unboxed arrays can be very fast. Like for list of integers:

```
histogram bounds xs = accumArray (+) 0 bounds [(x, 1) | x <- xs]
```

As String is not a member of Ix class, the question is: is it possible to build an array from list of strings?

Comment: Thanks for response! I've tried even just counting instances of each string (without length):
     freqMap =  M.fromListWith (+) [(c, 1) | c <- subs] 
But it looks like performance is still the same with group.sort version. Profiling also showed that most of time is spent in sorting or freqMap evaluation.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Data.HashMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.8.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#t:HashMap) instead? Could speed things up.

Comment: Thanks! HashMap worked significantly better, than other variants. Though it's still not unboxed array, but a tree, but I guess, it will take too much memory to index each of possible hash values into indexes.

Comment: You may be interested in [`hashtables`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables).

Comment: Yes, but how do I count with hashtable? I don't see any fromListWith or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Data.HashMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.8.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#t:HashMap) (lazy/strict) is a faster version of the vanilla haskell maps - using them may speed up your operations if the bottleneck is primarily the update/lookup speed.

And the best part is that you can keep the nice clean approach you've already written, and not have to write (usually uglier) code that interacts with arrays.

Comment: Thanks for advice, now sorting is not my bottleneck. I've got approximately 50% improvement in counting phase.